# Wordpress add image additional attribute

Tags: wordpress

When I insert an image to normal wordpress post and set the link to file i get code like:

```
<a href="http://...full.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-9" src="http://..thumb.jpg" alt="2966976762_813645a74d_o" width="400" height="400" /></a>
```

I need some script to add additional attribute to  element:

```
<a href="http://...full.jpg" data-size="1000x500">
```

I just don't to do this one by one every time when i upload photos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got it:

```
add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'imageAddSizeToLink', 20, 8);

function imageAddSizeToLink($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '') {

    $i = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'full');
    $html = str_replace("<a ", "<a data-size='{$i[1]}x{$i[2]}'", $html);

    return $html;
}
```